# Encontrar um número depois de uma palavra específica com grepl e regex {r}

Tags: r, regex

Olá, tenho uma lista de endereços e estou tentando verificar quais possuem numeração e quais não possuem. No entanto, eu tenho algumas strings que terminam com número e estou tentando criar uma regex para filtrar esses resultados. Eu não quero que retorne números que venham depois das palavras "rua" e "km".

```
> #exemplo:
> enderecos <- c("rua 5", "rua x, casa y", "km 18")
>
> #resultado esperado:
> FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

Agradeço quem puder me ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o seguinte padrão de expressão regular

```
(?:km|rua)\s\d{1,9}
```

Testei com os dados informados e outros também, parece ser suficiente.
Segue o [link de teste](http://regexr.com/3tct1)

Comment: Guilherme, essa expressão está me retornando o seguinte erro: _Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""(?:km|rua)+\s"_

Comment: Talvez a linguagem que você está usando considera a '\' como um caractere especial.
tente usar "\\" ou procure saber qual é a forma correta de se inserir a barra na linguagem que você está usando

Comment: Sim, era isso mesmo. Com (?:km|rua)\\s\\d{1,9} funcionou

Comment: Ótimo. fico feliz em ajudar.
Não esqueça de marcar a resposta correta

Answer (score 1):

A seguinte expressão regular deve resolver o problema:

```
"(?:km|rua)+\s*\D+?"
```

Apesar da pequena mostra de dados, acredito que se houver mais variações basta edita-las.

[Exemplo no Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Om33oo/2)

Comment: Olá Carlos, essa expressão está me retornando o erro _Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""(?:km|rua)+\s"_

Comment: Descobri como resolver, preciso de um \ antes dos \ s e \D :)